# Парсинг картинок requests

Tags: python, парсер, requests

Пытаюсь спарсить картинки с сайта

```
link = book.get('img')
print(link)
HEADERS = {
     'User-Agent': User_Agent
}
response = requests.get(link, headers = HEADERS)
try:
     with open(f"images/{book.get('name')}_{book.get('author')}.jpg", "wb") as file:
         file.write(response.content)
except:
     pass
```

Я хочу сохранять картинки с названиями в виде ссылок, или похожими на них. Ссылки выглядят следующим образом:

```
https://www.site.ru/files/1377/28/79/30/8.jpg
```

Из-за `/` и `.` в названии не получается сохранить такой файл. Можно ли как-то это обойти?
Сохранять картинки хотелось бы в виде

```
files/1377/28/79/30/8.jpg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'files/1377/28/79/30/8.jpg'.replace('/','_')
#'files_1377_28_79_30_8.jpg'
```

слэш в имени файла запрещён